# how to get attribute from other model in your django template

Tags: django, orm

SO I have these two models, One is Members other is PaymentDetail. What I want is all the members from Member model in my template which I can get from Members.object.all() but also I want the payment_status of all those members in my template next to them. I dont know how to do it as payment_status is not in the Member model.

```
class Members(models.Model ):
    user = models.ForeignKey(Users,verbose_name='User Id', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    com = models.ForeignKey(Committees, on_delete=models.CASCADE,verbose_name='Committee Name')
    mem_status = models.CharField( max_length=20,choices=MEMBER_STATUS, verbose_name='Member Status')
    mem_note = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)

class PaymentDetails(models.Model):
    mem = models.ForeignKey(Members,on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="payment_details",verbose_name='Memeber Phone no')
    com = models.ForeignKey(Committees, on_delete=models.CASCADE,verbose_name='Committee Name')
    payment_month = models.DateField(default=datetime.now())
    payment_amount_debit = models.IntegerField(null=True,blank=True)
    payment_amount_credit = models.IntegerField(null=True,blank=True)
    payment_status = models.CharField(max_length=16, choices=PAYMENT_DETAILS_CHOICES, default="1")
    payment_proof = models.ImageField(upload_to='images/')
    payment_note = models.TextField(null=True,blank=True)
```

I searched alot and Found out there is somehting called related name and setname, but I am kinda new so I am not getting the desired results by using them too.

Answer (score 0):

You can access to payment details object via a related name. I see you define `payment_details` so in HTML template you can access it by this:

`member.payment_details.all()`

There could be a performance issue because `payment_details.all()` will execute query to database. You can avoid this by using prefetch_related('payment_details') in django view. Exmaple:

`Member.objects.prefetch_related('payment_details')`